# How can I find a missing number in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: c++

Numbers should be input as:

> 53,55,57,58,54

Output:

> Missing number is 56

Input should be able to be as many numbers as wanted.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getMissingNo (int a[], int n)
{
    int i, total;
    total  = (n+1)*(n+2)/2;   
    for ( i = 0; i< n; i++)
       total -= a[i];
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    cout << "Enter number of numbers in sequence: ";
    int numInSeq;
    cin >> numInSeq;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter numbers in sequence: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < numInSeq; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    int miss = getMissingNo(a,numInSeq);
    cout << "Missing number: " << miss << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing I am missing is being able to enter the numbers separated by commas and I need to edit `getMissingNo` so it can be any sequence of numbers not just one that starts with 1.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution if you know the range.

- For a given range, let S be the sum of all the numbers within that range.
- For a given array with a missing number, let MS be the sum of the numbers in this array.

The missing number is **S - MS**

Comment: In fact, if you just record the maximum and minimum, you have the range.

Comment: Also, note that this only works if only one number is missing.